# override email template model

Tags: module, magento-1, overrides, model

I am trying to override a function in `Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php` the module i wrote is just a config that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Module> 
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <module>
                <rewrite>
                    <email_template_filter>Namespace_Module_Model_Email_Template_Filter</email_template_filter>
                </rewrite>
            </module>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

in `Namespace/Module/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php` I have

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Email_Template_Filter extends Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter
{...
    public function varDirective($construction)
    {
```

why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done small mistake `<module>` should be `<core>`

**Change from**

```
 <global>
        <models>
            <module>
                <rewrite>
                    <email_template_filter>Namespace_Module_Model_Email_Template_Filter</email_template_filter>
                </rewrite>
            </module>
       </models>
    </global>
```

**to**

```
<global>
        <models>
            <core>
                <rewrite>
                    <email_template_filter>Namespace_Module_Model_Email_Template_Filter</email_template_filter>
                </rewrite>
            </core>
       </models>
    </global>
```

Comment: edited the for: should be part you can erase that from answer